# require_once php file breaks script

Tags: php, require, vbulletin

I have the following script to download a file from my vbulletin 4 forum with hotlink protection.

```
 <?php


error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Allow direct file download (hotlinking)?
// Empty - allow hotlinking
// If set to nonempty value (Example: example.com) will only allow downloads when referrer contains this text
define('ALLOWED_REFERRER', '');

// Download folder, i.e. folder where you keep all files for download.
// MUST end with slash (i.e. "/" )
define('BASE_DIR','C:/Domains/xxxx.com/httpdocs/xxxx/files/');

// log downloads?  true/false
define('LOG_DOWNLOADS',true);

// log file name
define('LOG_FILE','downloads.log');

// Allowed extensions list in format 'extension' => 'mime type'
// If myme type is set to empty string then script will try to detect mime type 
// itself, which would only work if you have Mimetype or Fileinfo extensions
// installed on server.
$allowed_ext = array (

  // archives
  'zip' => 'application/zip',

  // documents
  'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
  'doc' => 'application/msword',
  'xls' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel',
  'ppt' => 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',

  // executables
  'exe' => 'application/octet-stream',

  // images
  'gif' => 'image/gif',
  'png' => 'image/png',
  'jpg' => 'image/jpeg',
  'jpeg' => 'image/jpeg',

  // audio
  'mp3' => 'audio/mpeg',
  'wav' => 'audio/x-wav',

  // video
  'mpeg' => 'video/mpeg',
  'mpg' => 'video/mpeg',
  'mpe' => 'video/mpeg',
  'mov' => 'video/quicktime',
  'avi' => 'video/x-msvideo'
);



####################################################################
###  DO NOT CHANGE BELOW
####################################################################

// If hotlinking not allowed then make hackers think there are some server problems
if (ALLOWED_REFERRER !== ''
&& (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) || strpos(strtoupper($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']),strtoupper(ALLOWED_REFERRER)) === false)
) {
  die("Internal server error. Please contact system administrator.");
}

// Make sure program execution doesn't time out
// Set maximum script execution time in seconds (0 means no limit)
set_time_limit(0);

if (!isset($_GET['f']) || empty($_GET['f'])) {
  die("Please specify file name for download.");
}

// Nullbyte hack fix
if (strpos($_GET['f'], "\0") !== FALSE) die('');

// Get real file name.
// Remove any path info to avoid hacking by adding relative path, etc.
$fname = basename($_GET['f']);

// Check if the file exists
// Check in subfolders too
function find_file ($dirname, $fname, &$file_path) {

  $dir = opendir($dirname);

  while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if (empty($file_path) && $file != '.' && $file != '..') {
      if (is_dir($dirname.'/'.$file)) {
        find_file($dirname.'/'.$file, $fname, $file_path);
      }
      else {
        if (file_exists($dirname.'/'.$fname)) {
          $file_path = $dirname.'/'.$fname;
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  }

} // find_file

// get full file path (including subfolders)
$file_path = '';
find_file(BASE_DIR, $fname, $file_path);

if (!is_file($file_path)) {
  die("File does not exist. Make sure you specified correct file name."); 
}

// file size in bytes
$fsize = filesize($file_path); 

// file extension
$fext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($fname,"."),1));

// check if allowed extension
if (!array_key_exists($fext, $allowed_ext)) {
  die("Not allowed file type."); 
}

// get mime type
if ($allowed_ext[$fext] == '') {
  $mtype = '';
  // mime type is not set, get from server settings
  if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {
    $mtype = mime_content_type($file_path);
  }
  else if (function_exists('finfo_file')) {
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME); // return mime type
    $mtype = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
    finfo_close($finfo);  
  }
  if ($mtype == '') {
    $mtype = "application/force-download";
  }
}
else {
  // get mime type defined by admin
  $mtype = $allowed_ext[$fext];
}

// Browser will try to save file with this filename, regardless original filename.
// You can override it if needed.

if (!isset($_GET['fc']) || empty($_GET['fc'])) {
  $asfname = $fname;
}
else {
  // remove some bad chars
  $asfname = str_replace(array('"',"'",'\\','/'), '', $_GET['fc']);
  if ($asfname === '') $asfname = 'NoName';
}

// set headers
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: $mtype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$asfname\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: " . $fsize);

// download
// @readfile($file_path);
$file = @fopen($file_path,"rb");
if ($file) {
  while(!feof($file)) {
    print(fread($file, 1024*8));
    flush();
    if (connection_status()!=0) {
      @fclose($file);
      die();
    }
  }
  @fclose($file);
}


// log downloads
if (!LOG_DOWNLOADS) die();

$f = @fopen(LOG_FILE, 'a+');
if ($f) {
  @fputs($f, date("m.d.Y g:ia")."  ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."  ".$fname."\n");
  @fclose($f);
}


?>
```

This works great, however i would like to restrict it to only members logged into my vbulletin 4 forum and on specific usergroups. If i add the following code to the script to pull in the user data from vbulletin, it breaks the script instead of asking to download the file when you use the link http://xxxx.com/download.php?f=test.zip it just says "Please specify file name for download."

```
// Get vBulletin session stuff so we can determine if the user is logged in, etc.
require_once('./global.php');
```

Is there a way to get it to work when calling the global.php file also? I'm yet to actually put in the if statements but they should be the easy bits!

Thanks
Mathew

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right filepath to that `.php` file? As you `require` it to be there, it will fail the rest of the script is it *isn't* there.

Comment: The php script above is run in the root directory and also the global.php file is in the root so i would assume ./global.php would be ok? I have had other errors about not finding the file if i change the path to global but also the global.php file has require lines it in and it also complains about now finding them. Stream not available or somthing along those lines